# Why does this code snippet produce radically different assembly code in C and C++?

Tags: c++, c, gcc, assembly, simd

```
struct v {
    int val[16];
};

struct v test(struct v a, struct v b) {
    struct v res;

    for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++)
        res.val[i] = a.val[i] + b.val[i];

    return res;
}
```

Compiling as C++, GCC 7.2 emits:

```
  push r10
  vmovdqu32 zmm0, ZMMWORD PTR [rsp+16]
  mov rax, rdi
  vpaddd zmm0, zmm0, ZMMWORD PTR [rsp+80]
  lea r10, [rsp+16]
  vmovdqu32 ZMMWORD PTR [rdi], zmm0
  pop r10
```

Compiling as C:

```
  lea r10, [rsp+8]
  and rsp, -64
  mov rax, rdi
  push QWORD PTR [r10-8]
  push rbp
  mov rbp, rsp
  push r10
  vmovdqu32 zmm0, ZMMWORD PTR [r10]
  vpaddd zmm0, zmm0, ZMMWORD PTR [r10+64]
  vmovdqa64 ZMMWORD PTR [rbp-112], zmm0
  vmovdqa64 xmm0, XMMWORD PTR [rbp-112]
  vmovups XMMWORD PTR [rdi], xmm0
  vmovdqa64 xmm0, XMMWORD PTR [rbp-96]
  vmovups XMMWORD PTR [rdi+16], xmm0
  vmovdqa64 xmm0, XMMWORD PTR [rbp-80]
  vmovups XMMWORD PTR [rdi+32], xmm0
  vmovdqa64 xmm0, XMMWORD PTR [rbp-64]
  vmovups XMMWORD PTR [rdi+48], xmm0
  pop r10
  pop rbp
  lea rsp, [r10-8]
```

Compiled as C vs. C++ on the Godbolt compiler explorer:

clang x86 asm: https://godbolt.org/g/FfrKTf
gcc x86 asm: https://godbolt.org/g/SZQqqt

The same code snippet produces significantly different code for C and C++ in both gcc and clang:

- The loop is auto-vectorized differently: gcc using unaligned loads / stores but g++ using scalar until an alignment boundary, with `-march=sandybridge` or anything narrower than AVX2.

  This isn't x86-specific: the same thing happens with auto-vectorization for AArch64 SIMD.
- The C version actually stores results to a local `res` on the stack and then uses copies SIMD copies from there to the return-value pointer (sometimes with different vector width for the copy than for the loop that just stored the data).

  With auto-vectorization disabled (`-fno-tree-vectorize`), gcc still uses SIMD load/store to copy the results.

Does anyone know why that is so?

Is there some alignment guarantee that is in the C++ standard but is not in the C standard? Is this an ABI issue? Or is that some weird compilation option on compiler explorer?

Comment: Can you please copy & paste the code and the assembler in your question?

Comment: Alright added it to the question.

Comment: Because C++ has copy elision? Try `-fno-elide-constructors`.

Comment: @hl3mukkel add the *code* to your question, not links to external sites.

Comment: @KerrekSB This indeed seems to be it! Is this the same feature as Return value optimization?

Comment: I'm a little confused as to why you posted this both on SO and on r/cpp

Comment: Looks like missed-optimizations for gcc and clang with the C front-end vs. the C++ front-end.  They must be giving different internal representations of the program to the middle end, so the C version does extra copying to a local on the stack.  ICC makes the same asm with / without `-xc`.

Comment: @hl3mukkel: Sort of kind of. RVO is an optimization that is justified by copy elision.

Comment: @Justin It seems like a rather complicated question and since stackoverflow's userbase is a lot bigger I thought I would give it a try, how exactly does this confuse you?

Comment: @KerrekSB Alright then, thanks for the clarification! If you write an answer I'll mark it as accepted.

Comment: @hl3mukkel: No, I don't really know why this couldn't be done in C under an "as-if" rule. I can speculate that the way you think about functions in C would perhaps not suggest this naturally, but I don't think such an optimization would be invalid.

Comment: Copy elision is not necessary in order to optimize anything in this code. C doesn't have copy elision because it's not necessary. There are no copy constructors with possible side effects to elide away.

Comment: Still would like the off-site content brought here please..

Comment: @hl3mukkel: When Justin said "confused" he was just being polite, and actually wanted to point out that cross-posting is (and always has been) considered poor netiquette.

Comment: I think ultimately this'll just be "because they're different compilers underneath and they just are different in some ways, with [compiler] code that focuses on some approaches at the possible expense of others"

Comment: Not clicking the link, certainly not a shortened one. God knows where it would take me.

Comment: Downvoting just because after several requests from many users OP does not care to bring asm code here.

Comment: Could this be a difference in default alignments in c vs c++?  IIRC, I have had to add alignment attributes to c code in order to get full vectorization.

Comment: @user902384 : You must be new here, but godbolt is a well respected domain and heavily used by authors of questions and answers especially in the C/C++/Assembly tags.

Comment: I see no assembly here, external links are useless for stackoverflow questions (and answers).

Comment: There is no reason to expect different compilers (or front ends) to produce the same code.  The problem here is expectations not code or languages.  If you get two or more to produce the same code, then that was good luck...

Comment: @user902384 Am I not allowed to sleep and monitor this question 24/7? Not everyone lives in the same timezones, stop being ignorant.

Comment: @old_timer When you have relatively obvious optimizations I expect them to be done in both compilers, normally C and C++ are highly optimized so I was surprised C didn't pick up this one.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I apologize, I was sleeping so I couldn't add the code, some mod has added it though.

Comment: @hl3mukkel: Wait, you mean to say you don't code while sleeping? What sort of dev are you!

Comment: @MichaelPetch: While that's true, the very fact that recognition and trust of an off-site domain is subject to personal experience is a good part of the reason not to rely on them.

Comment: @hl3mukkel I will remove the downvote but seekers of knowledge do not sleep easily.

Comment: @hl3mukkel well that is what I said is the problem is with expectations...even relatively obvious ones.  Not difficult to find missed optimization opportunities in compilers.  No reason to expect they will catch them all nor will the same compiler with different front ends nor different compilers.

Comment: Two different languages give different outputs. Not that surprising.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to compiler dumps C Gimple IR works intermediate object on stack (which is then copied to return value)

```
$ gcc ../tmp.c -fdump-tree-gimple -O2 -S -std=c99
$ cat tmp.c.004t.gimple
...
    <D.1621>:
    D.1626 = a.val[i];
    D.1627 = b.val[i];
    D.1628 = D.1626 + D.1627;
    res.val[i] = D.1628;
    i = i + 1;
    <D.1622>:
    if (i <= 15) goto <D.1621>; else goto <D.1623>;
    <D.1623>:
  }
  <retval> = res;
  return <retval>;
```

whereas C++ one operates directly on retval temp:

```
$ g++ ../tmp.c -fdump-tree-gimple -O2 -S
$ cat tmp.c.004t.gimple
    <D.2250>:
    D.2254 = a.val[i];
    D.2255 = b.val[i];
    D.2256 = D.2254 + D.2255;
    <retval>.val[i] = D.2256;
    i = i + 1;
    <D.2251>:
    if (i <= 15) goto <D.2250>; else goto <D.2248>;
    <D.2248>:
  }
  return <retval>;
```

AFAIR C and C++ Gimple generators do not share code so anomalies like this are to be expected. I encourage you to report this in [GCC Bugzilla](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/) as it's probly a common performance issue.